# Java can't seem to find my native libraries

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to run my program from my jar, called PViz.jar. The jar is sitting in a directory with all of its dependent jars and the .so files that they depend on. I am using Mac OS X. When I run this:

```
java -cp PViz.jar pviz.PVizStart
```

Then I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError saying "no jogl in java.library.path". This is reasonable, i'm using jogl.jar which makes use of the native library libjogl.so.

So I run this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -cp PViz.jar pviz.PVizStart
```

and I get the same error. But libjogl.so is in the current directory! I figured maybe I needed to give the whole path, so I tried this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/bla/bla/bla/libjogl.so -cp PViz.jar pviz.PVizStart
```

and it still gives me the same UnsatisifedLinkError. Argh!

Comment: Have you tried to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Can you set the value of the environment variable "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" to your .so location and try it?

Comment: i would like to set this when I run it. i'm trying to make it easy to run on a friend's system without messing with his environment variables.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could also be a permissions problem. Maybe libjogl.so needs to be executable? (Try `chmod u+x libjogl.so`).

Comment: The library works fine when I run it from Eclipse so I doubt it is a permissions issue.

Comment: Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't do anything.

Comment: Does your library have any dependencies? Are they in the path also?

Comment: Argh. Peter you're right. I didn't realize that the ".jnilib" files were required too. Java could really do with some more intuitive error messages!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://cs.gmu.edu/~jchen/graphics/jogl/notes/joglSetup.html) is a step by step explanation on how to setup jogl on different operating systems, OS X included.

Comment: eclipse does a fair amount of voodoo.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the lib in a static initializer in one of the main classes of your app.

Example (Copied + renamed from one of my projects):

```
public class MainClass {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary( "Your_native_lib_file_name" ); // Note: do not include the file extension!
    }
}
```

The native lib should be in the same directory as your jar.

Comment: I get the exact same error. I tried it doing this with -Djava.library.path-. and -Djava.library.path=/exact/path/to/dir/ and I still get the stupid UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: I used System.loadLibrary("jogl"); where libjogl.so is in the same directory as the jar.

Comment: Are the native libs sitting next to their respective jar files in your directories?

Comment: Use System.loadLibrary("libjogl");

Comment: Yes they are Andy. I'll try that I guess.

Comment: same error. this time it complains about libjogl instead of jogl. same diff :(

Comment: You needed to add " " around path. Like so -Djava.library.path="/bla/bla/bla/libjogl.so"